# formatting JSON with a dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, format

I am writing some code for technical users to pass in JSON with placeholders for variables, accompanied by a dict to define each of those variables. I want to replace those variables with the values and ultimately need to get it into a Python dict. Imagine I start with this:

```
>>> json_in = """
{
    "sidebar": {
        "type": "sidebar",
        "title": "<h1>Vulnerability Data</h1>",
        "description": {md_html}
    },
    "widgets": [
        {
            "name": "Map",
            "itemId": {item_id},
            "showNavigation": false
        }
    ]
}"""
>>> args = {'md_html': '<super_long_html_string>', 'item_id': 'abcdef12345'}
```

If I try to do a format like `json_in.format(**args)`, I just get a KeyError when it hits the first opening curly brace (before "sidebar"), which format tries to read. Doubling the curly braces escapes them in `format()`, but this JSON can be thousands of lines long, so it's really not something I want to make people do a ton of reformatting on. I guess I can try to edit the JSON with Python before the `format()`. I'd have to avoid mangling the curly braces from the formatting strings, so this seems like it's getting needlessly complex. Python usually has simple solutions, so what am I missing?

---

Another path I went down is just to create it as a Python dict in the first place. It's easy to search for JSONisms and replace with the Python equivalents (e.g.: `false` to `False`, `true` to `True`). Instead of formatting strings (`{item_id}`), I just use variables (`item_id`) to end up with something like this:

```
>>> md_html = '<super_long_html_string>'
>>> item_id = 'abcdef12345'
>>> dict_in = {
    "sidebar": {
        "type": "sidebar",
        "title": "<h1>Vulnerability Data</h1>",
        "description": md_html
    },
    "widgets": [
        {
            "name": "Map",
            "itemId": item_id,
            "showNavigation": False
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that the variables `md_html` and `item_id` are hard-coded in this example, and I want to accept whatever the user passes in (see the `args` dict above). If I could create a dict with placeholders and replace them with inputs supplied, that would solve my problem.

Comment: Generally with string formatting, you have to deal with the special characters. `{` and `}` for `.format`, for example. Other options are templates https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings or the old school `%` formatting may be more natural to use in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`jq` library](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) to define such a JSON template.

```
import jq


json_in = """
{
    "sidebar": {
        "type": "sidebar",
        "title": "<h1>Vulnerability Data</h1>",
        "description": $md_html
    },
    "widgets": [
        {
            "name": "Map",
            "itemId": $item_id,
            "showNavigation": false
        }
    ]
}"""


args = {'md_html': '<super_long_html_string>', 'item_id': 'abcdef12345'}

result = jq.compile(json_in, args=args).input("")
```

Comment: Seems like this and Template Strings (see above) will both solve the problem, but I accepted this as the answer since it also validates the JSON. I wasn't originally too worried about validating the JSON, since the user starts with it valid. But I couldn't even type up this question without screwing it up (I'm missing quotations around my variables), so clearly validation is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Template Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) if you have control over `json_in`.

```py
from string import Template
json_in = """
{
    "sidebar": {
        "type": "sidebar",
        "title": "<h1>Vulnerability Data</h1>",
        "description": $md_html
    },
    "widgets": [
        {
            "name": "Map",
            "itemId": $item_id,
            "showNavigation": false
        }
    ]
}"""
args = {'md_html': '<super_long_html_string>', 'item_id': 'abcdef12345'}
Template(json_in).substitute(args)
```

Output

```json
{
    "sidebar": {
        "type": "sidebar",
        "title": "<h1>Vulnerability Data</h1>",
        "description": <super_long_html_string>
    },
    "widgets": [
        {
            "name": "Map",
            "itemId": abcdef12345,
            "showNavigation": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I suppose you'll want quotes around the strings, I just left the json as close to your question as possible.

Comment: `Template` won't ensure that the result is valid JSON, which can lead to significant problems if you don't sanitize the argument values before substitution.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer. I accepted the `jq` answer below, since that includes validation, but this basically does the same thing. What I like about this is it doesn't need any additional libs.